# Can HTAs be used to automate web browsing?

Tags: automation, jscript, hta

I am new to HTAs. I just read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and am a bit confused.

**Can I use HTAs to automate browsing?** Say I want to download a web page and fill in a form automatically, i.e. from a script. How would an HTA help me do this, if at all? It's important that the JavaScript code in the downloaded page is run as usual. I should be able to enter somehow and fill in the form after it has finished initializing, just as if I were a human agent.

Comment: That's an interesting question. I would guess that would be hard to do, because of how HTAs and iframes interact, but I'm not sure. Have you tried anything?

Comment: @freginold Yes I have :) The automation is amazing! I can sit and watch an invisible agent do all the things I used to do manually on the web.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to open an IE window, as follows:

```
var IE = new ActiveXObject("InternetExplorer.Application");
```

Then navigate the IE window to the webpage you want:

```
IE.Navigate("www.example.com");
```

Wether your IE window is visible or invisible, it's up to you. Use **Visible** property to make it visible:

```
IE.Visible = true;
```

Then, you should wait until the webpage is completely loaded and then run a function that takes your desired actions. To do so, first, get the HTML document object from the webpage using **Document** property of IE object, then repeatedly check the **readyState** property of document object. In the code below, it is assumed that you have a function named myFunc, which takes your desired actions on the webpage. (For example, modifying the contents of the webpage.)

```
var doc = IE.Document;
interval = setInterval(function() {
    try
    {
        if (doc.readyState == "complete")
        {
            myFunc();
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }
    catch (e) {}
}, 1000);
```

In the function **myFunc**, you can do anything you want with the webpage since you have HTML document object stored in **doc** variable. You can also use **parentWindow** property to get the HTML window object.